# SQL Server: update to match and replace only exact words

Tags: sql-server, replace, sql-update, exact-match

I want to match an exact word and replace it with another word.

Here is the SQL Server query that I am using:

```
UPDATE BODYCONTENT 
SET BODY = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(BODY AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'Test' , 'prod') AS NTEXT) 
WHERE BODY COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS LIKE '%Test%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS;
```

What this query is doing:

'Test','test','TEST' is updated into 'prod'  -- This is expected.

'Test2','TestTest', 'Fastest' is updated into 'prod' - I want to avoid this behavior.

Please help.

Other queries I tried but didn't work:

```
UPDATE BODYCONTENT 
SET BODY = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(BODY AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'Test' , 'prod') AS NTEXT) 
WHERE BODY COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS LIKE '%[^A-Za-z0-9]Test[^A-Za-z0-9]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS;
```

And when I do a select for 'Test' using the below query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.BODYCONTENT 
WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), BODY) = N'Test';
```

It is not returning anything. But I could get results using the below queries:

```
  SELECT BODY 
  FROM dbo.BODYCONTENT 
  WHERE BODY LIKE '%Test%';

  SELECT BODY 
  FROM dbo.BODYCONTENT 
  WHERE BODY COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS like '%TEST%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS;
```

Here is the column value:

```
Test testtest Test1 Test TEST
```

Expected result:

```
prod testtest Test1 prod prod
```

Current result:

```
prod prodprod prod1 prod prod
```

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: I think if you just use `LIKE 'test'` instead of `LIKE '%test%'` it will match the string "test" only, regardless of upper/lower case. The % characters are acting as wildcards and will match anything.

Comment: @JohnRC, Like 'test' returns nothing.

Comment: The ntext datatype in here is just adding a level of complication that is beyond unnecessary. That datatype has been deprecated for more than a decade in favor of nvarchar(max). Despite that I think the problem is that you want to change only whole words within a larger string. To accomplish that you are going to need to split your string into words. For that you need a string splitter. Depending on the version it may or may not have STRING_SPLIT. Then you would be able to replace only those with the entire word matching. And finally you would have to shove the words back together again.

Comment: I would like add reference to this post here:https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151550/sql-server-ntext-columns-and-string-manipulation

Comment: Sean and marc, Thank you for your comments. Yes, nText is adding complexity.

Comment: Is `Test testtest Test1 Test TEST` a single column value?

Comment: @iamdave, yes it is, the column BODY stores large texts.

Comment: @Ilakk  In that case my answer should do what you need it to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am getting the impression that all the different versions of `test` are within the same row value, which is why you are stating that the suggested `like 'test'` is not working.

Based on this, the below is rather ugly but functional per your requirements:

```
declare @t table(s ntext);
insert into @t values('Test testtest Test1 Test TEST');

select s as Original
        ,ltrim(rtrim(replace(
                            replace(
                                    replace(N' ' + cast(s as nvarchar(max)) + N' '  -- Add a single space before and after value,
                                            ,' ','<>'                               -- then replace all spaces with any two characters.
                                            )
                                    ,'>test<','>prod<'      -- Use these two characters to identify single instances of 'test'
                                    )
                            ,'<>',' '       -- Then replace the delimiting characters with spaces and trim the value.
                            )
                    )
            ) as Updated
from @t;
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|           Original            |            Updated            |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Test testtest Test1 Test TEST | prod testtest Test1 prod prod |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

---

The use of `<>` in place of spaces is due to SQL Server's default behaviour to ignore trailing spaces in string comparisons.  These can be any two characters, but I find these to be aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I wanted. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: I do have one more question. I have this collation set in my db - Latin1_General_CS_AS. This is making the searches case sensitive and How do I search for my search string case insensitive?

Comment: Clue: The below sql works for me: UPDATE BODYCONTENT SET BODY = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(BODY as nvarchar(max)), 'test' , 'prod') as ntext) WHERE BODY COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS like '%test%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS;      I think i gotta use the where clause.

Comment: Child Question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992508/sql-server-to-search-case-insensitive-where-the-collate-latin1-general-cs-as-i

Comment: This is a neat solution +1 - Just a suggestion: use substring instead of ltrim and rtrim like this: `SUBSTRING( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE ( '>' + CAST( @txt AS Varchar(MAX) ) + '<' , ' ', '<>' ), '>test<', '>prod<' ), '<>', ' ' ), 2, LEN(@txt))`

Comment: Thank you JohnRC and iamdave. This query is not replacing the following strings                                                                        Test   --- >  test with a lot of white spaces in the beginning,  %test% - test with special characters. Please suggest me a suitable solution. I appreciate it

Comment: Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50994199/ntext-and-string-manipulation-sql-server. Please feel free to answer this.

Comment: @iamdave, your answer is very helpful but query is not replacing the following strings:           Test --- > test with a lot of white spaces in the beginning, %test% - test with special characters. Please advice when you find time.