# Replace part of text in sql database

Tags: replace

I need to replace parts of text using the following query:

```
UPDATE table_name SET field = REPLACE(field, 'old', 'new')
```

The problem is that the query must not replace "old.jpg" or "oldcar" and so on, but ONLY "old".

Can we use something like below?

```
WHERE field LIKE 'old'
```

Comment: You might like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50984816/1626878

Comment: Thank you Sahil,

Comment: What database, DBMS, are you using?

Comment: Thank you Sahil,

I need to replace about 20.000 different item numbers with 20.000 different link to the related objects: i prepared a xlsx with 20.000 queries like this

UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE (field,"10.300.17","<a href=\"link-to-product-10.300.17/\">10.300.17</a>");

it works well, but unfortunately replaces also 10.300.17.jpg and so on.

Comment: is a standard MySQL innoDB

Comment: Why can't you do `WHERE field = '10.300.17'`, it will not match 10.300.17.jpg? What am I missing?

Comment: Hello Joakim and thanks: the field is a (quite long) text field and in this text you can find both "10.300.17" and also 10.300.17.jpg" . and I can't use << WHERE field = '10.300.17'>> because the query does not find anything to replace.