# MYSQL - REPLACE() function to entire string instead of part of it

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-cleaning

In column 1 I have 4 values

```
N
No
Y
Yes
```

I tried to replace N with No and Y with Yes with the following code

```
UPDATE nashupdated
SET SoldAsVacant = REPLACE(SoldAsVacant, "N", "No"),
    SoldAsVacant = REPLACE(SoldAsVacant, "Y", "Yes");
```

However, it also replaces the "Y" in "Yes" for example, becoming "Yeses"

How should I write the function so that it looks for the entire string only?

Comment: Try this method:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50974562/sql-server-update-to-match-and-replace-only-exact-words

Comment: Add `WHERE SoldAsVacant IN ('Y', 'N')`

Answer (score 1):

Using an IF you could do it like this

```
UPDATE nashupdated
SET SoldAsVacant = IF(SoldAsVacant = 'N', 'No', SoldAsVacant ),
    SoldAsVacant = IF(SoldAsVacant = 'Y', 'Yes', SoldAsVacant );
```

This tests the existing value of the column and if it matches sets it to the new value and if not sets it to the existing value.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
UPDATE nashupdated
SET SoldAsVacant = REPLACE(SoldAsVacant, "N", "No"),
    SoldAsVacant = REPLACE(SoldAsVacant, "Y", "Yes")
WHERE SoldAsVacant IN ('Y', 'N');
```

This is more useful than IF/CASE, especially if `SoldAsVacant` is indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Way

```
UPDATE nashupdated set SoldAsVacant ='Yes' Where SoldAsVacant ='Y';
 
UPDATE nashupdated set SoldAsVacant ='No'  Where SoldAsVacant ='N';
```

Comment: Check this for how to properly format code https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE nashupdated
SET SoldAsVacant = CASE SoldAsVacant 
                     WHEN 'N' THEN 'No'
                     WHEN 'Y' THEN 'Yes'
                   END
WHERE SoldAsVacant IN ('Y', 'N');
```

Or:

```
UPDATE nashupdated
SET SoldAsVacant = CASE WHEN SoldAsVacant = 'N' THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END
WHERE SoldAsVacant IN ('Y', 'N');
```

Answer (score 0):

A fun way uses a derived table to lookup the values:

```
update nashupdated n join
       (select 'N' as old_value, 'No' as new_value union all
        select 'Y' as old_value, 'Yes' as new_value
       ) x
       on n.SoldAsVacant = x.old_value
    set n.SoldAsVacant = x.new_value;
```

What is nice about this approach is that the `join` filters down to only the rows that need to be updated and the values are mentioned only once.

Comment: There is no *fun* and nothing is *nice* when you use UNION ALL and then a join for such a simple requirement which can be done in just 1 scan of the table. This is terrible code.